# How to test a javascript method which returns a Promise object using mocha-phantomjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, mocha-phantomjs

I have a couple of unit tests written in mocha which I'm able to run on the browser. I need to automate these tests on a server machine where I will be writing a CLI commands. The problem is when I try to run the tests using PhantomJS I get an error saying

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Promise
>       at file:///C:/Halosys/halosysus_jslibrary/dest/hmsdk.js:5061
>       at file:///C:/Halosys/halosysus_jslibrary/tests/ISession_Spec.js:29
>       at callFnAsync
>
> (file:///C:/Halosys/halosysus_jslibrary/node_modules/mocha/mo
>   cha.js:4506)

I'm confused on how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS does not support promises, more information is available on the [PhantomJS issue tracker (#12401)](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12401).

You can try using the libraries [es6-promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) or [promise-polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) to augment the functionality for now.

Comment: I have tried the first one before. Tried the other one as well. In both cases i tried add requirejs into the dependencies and add the require statements. Still i get an error saying Can't find variable: require.Can you tell me the correct way of including the require module?

Comment: another problem is i do not want to write tests to return promises. The Promise object is returned from the method i'm testing.

Comment: @PradeepKeshavprakash It's a bit too broad of a question without seeing your specific implementation, I suggest you open a separate question for that showing some example code as well to reproduce the error.

Comment: no...i need to just know for any testing framework...how can i include requirejs properly to use it for including the libraries/plugins which u mentioned in ur first answer.

Comment: Without knowing what you've tried there is not much I can suggest, I don't use it myself. There is a ticket on the mocha-phantomjs repo, https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-phantomjs/issues/80 that suggests ways to enable access to *require* in your tests. Even though the ticket itself is old (and refers to Node as well) it could be applicable to your situation as well.